# How to resolve 'gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h: No such file or directory'

Tags: chromium

I am trying to compile chromium source on ubuntu 10.10. But I get this "gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h: No such file or directory" error. Can you please tell how can I fix it?  I have the '/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkpixbuf.h', so I should have gdkpixbuf dev package right?
(since it said '/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkpixbuf.h:37: fatal error: gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h: No such file or directory'

```
$ make out/Debug/chrome
  CXX(target) out/Debug/obj.target/app_base/app/active_window_watcher_x.o
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcairo.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:33,
                 from app/active_window_watcher_x.cc:6:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkpixbuf.h:37: fatal error: gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [out/Debug/obj.target/app_base/app/active_window_watcher_x.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 9):

There's a generic “teach a man to fish…” answer here, too:

Install the `apt-file` package, and use it to search for the package containing the file you need.  In this case, you get:

```
└─(14:36:%)── apt-file search gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev: /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h
libgfcui-dev: /usr/include/gfc-2.0/gfc/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.hh
lsb-build-desktop3: /usr/include/lsb3/gtk-2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h
```

which has (surprisingly) returned more than one result.  `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev` is the package you're after.

Answer (score 6):

I have both of the referenced packages installed and have had similar issues. In 10.10 it seems that the gdk-pixbuf includes are stored in their own directory off of /usr/include, whereas in previous versions they had been lumped in with gtk-2.0. If you have installed `libgtk2.0-dev` and `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev` then you'll need to execute:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk-pixbuf
```

This will create a symbolic link to the new gdk-pixbuf directory where it had been located previously.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. It seems like a distribution bug in 10.10. Merely installing libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev did not fix the problem.

Comment: +1 this worked on a Mac also.

Answer (score 1):

You have gdkpixbuf.h, which is not the same as gdk-pixbuf.h.  Note the dash, they are two different files.

greyfade is probably correct in you needing that package greyfade mentions, you should probably install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev as well since gdk-pixbuf.h is in the libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev package.

Doing an "aptitude build-dep chromium-browser" should download all of the development packages you need to manually install the chromium-browser source package for 10.10.  It should help even if you're pulling straight from chromium itself - you're going to need those development files anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, please install `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev` first:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
```

Then:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk-pixbuf
```

Comment: I think it is just a bug of 10.10, 11.04+ will not happen this error.

Answer (score 1):

From the [GTK+ Reference Manual](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/gtk-compiling.html) you should tell the compiler where to find the GTK+ header files and libraries. This is done with the pkg-config utility.

```
$ pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0
```

Or to use the "backticks" feature of the shell.

```
$ cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` hello.c -o hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `libgtk2.0-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the folder `gdk-pixbuf` from `/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0` to `/usr/include/gtk-2.0`. That did the trick for me.